# jQuery + CSS: switch to "loading"

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following set up:

```
<div class="click red"></div>
<div class="click green"></div>
<div class="click blue"></div>
```

and when "click" is clicked I want to add the class "load" to the div. I have managed this fine, but "red" "green" and "blue" all have a background image set so I need to remove that class. Now, I know how to do this the sloppy way, I take the class for the dib "click blue" (as returned by jquery) and then strip out what I need and replace it **but** this is incredibly sloppy and I can't see it being the proper method.

What's the proper way to approach this? I need to remove the second class from the div and replace it with the class "load". Is there some sort of method for calling each class individually, .attr("class")[2]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the class is "click", you can *set* the class, rather then add/removing it, like this:

```
$('div').attr('class', 'click load');
```

If you *know* the classes (not sure if this is a simplified example) you want to remove, you can do this:

```
$("div").removeClass('red green blue').addClass('load');
```

---

*Edit: Based on comments* - You can store the class using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and grab it later to restore it after the load, like this:

In your click function:

```
$.data(this, 'class', $(this).attr('class')); //store the original class
$(this).attr('class', 'click load');          //set loading class
```

Then to restore it later:

```
$(this).attr('class', $.data(this, 'class')); //restore orignal class
```

Comment: I need to retain the latter class for reverting after though. I guess the method would be to create a variable containing the current class, then replace it with "click load" and then revert back to the variable? Sounds workable, thanks!

Comment: It's fine, I know how, I was just asking about the theory :-) I'll tick your answer whenever the site lets me (10 minute wait). Thanks!

Comment: @user265331 - Alrighty :) I added it anyway, in case anyone in the future finds this useful as well.